# Android passing Intent information from many activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

To try and help on the clarity of the description of the problem I will use Activity A,B and C.

Activity A is Application main menu.

Activity B where the TextViews are

Activity C where the Edit Views are.

Note Activity B and C are only connected via Activity A i.e. to get from C to B two different intents are used C to A then A to B

Question; Is it possible to pass information from Activity C (the edittexts) to Activity B (set the textviews to that of the editTexts). I believe I could use intents but I am not sure how this will work.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't go from C to B? If so, you can pass the data from C to A and store in a temporary variable then pass that to B in a new `Intent`

Comment: Create a common place and try to set and get the values from the common place.

Comment: What makes a relationship between `B` and `C` impossible?

Comment: I guess I could make C go to B. Would it then be possible @ninetwozero

Comment: @Dan1676: You just need to `.putExtra(key, value)` on the `Intent` before you start it. I've added an answer with a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityB.java:`

```
public void startActivityC() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    intent.putExtra("key1", "value1");
    intent.putExtra("key2", "value2");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`ActivityC.java:`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Intent intentFromB = getIntent();
    String value1 = intentFromB.getStringExtra("key1");
    String value2 = intentFromB.getStringExtra("key2");

    // Do something with value1 & value2
}
```

Hope this helps!